# Trying to pass checkbox value in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

I am working on an app using Express, Node.js and Mongo.
I have various values that are being passed through to my database but I seem to be having problems with passing back a checkbox value.

I am trying to have a series of checkboxes and only pass their values back to the database when the checkbox is checked.

So far I have tried this in my index.jade

```
input#inputTestCheckbox(type='checkbox', name='List', checked=(true===false ? "checked" : undefined))
|   List
```

and I have this in my global.js

```
'test': $('#addUser fieldset input#inputTestCheckbox').val()
```

So far this does not function. If i put a value in the input, it will always get passed even if the checkbox is not checked.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction here? I seem to be missing something and can not seem to figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try:

```
  input#inputTestCheckbox(type="checkbox" name="list" checked=false value="1" required=false)
```

And then access it via **list.value**